# Are all of the signals sent from the terminal gets sent to the foreground process group?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

When you press `Ctrl+C` in the terminal, a `SIGINT` signal will be sent to the foreground process group.

Now there are other signals that you can send in the terminal (for example: `Ctrl+Z`). Are all of these signals get sent to the foreground process group also, or are there some signals that get sent to the background process groups?

Answer (score 1):

All keyboard signals are sent to the foreground process group only.

Sometimes a signal is sent to all processes in the session but those are not generated by the terminal. When the shell (at least`bash`) receives `SIGHUP` then it sends this signal (by default) to all its child processes. And `bash` can be configured to send `SIGHUP` to all jobs when it exits (`huponexit`).